# Extending ESP8266-01 GPIO

Tags: esp8266

I had bought a couple of ESP8266-01 chips a while ago and decided to use them.

I just found out that they only have 2 pins for GPIO, and I'll need more for a project.

I was thinking, is it possible to extend the GPIO so I can get at least 6 pins or more? A friend recommended me to buy a CD74HC4067 Digital/Analog Multiplexer, but I'm not sure if it'll work, so I prefer to not take the risk.

If it works, how can I hook it into my ESP8266?

Comment: Those things are so cheap these days, why not just buy a few that have more GPIO on them. I have one with 10 I/O that cost me $3 (including shipping.) Doesn't seem worthwhile to worry about and/or add uncertainty with I/O extenders you know little about when you can simply get the I/O you need right out of the box.

Comment: @jonk where did you buy yours? Could I have a link?

Comment: It's like this: http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-NodeMcu-Lua-ESP8266-CH340G-ESP-12E-Wireless-WIFI-Internet-Development-Board-/192076345156?hash=item2cb8a46f44:g:TXAAAOSwnHZYXdzr There are many other incarnations of these devices, though.

Comment: The question is formulated in a confusing way. You didn't bought "a couple of ESP8266-01 chips". You bought "a couple of ESP8266-01 **modules**" (based on the ESP8266 **chip**, which has plenty of GPIO, even if only two of them are routed out of the module).

Comment: @dim Sorry, I should have worded it better. Anyways, thanks for the replies, I'll buy a Wemos D1 board and use it for my needs. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I'll purchase a Wemos D1 board which has a good amount of GPIO pins and is easier to program than a ESP8266-01 module.